# Python diagrams output image size

Tags: python, diagram

I am using Python [diagrams](https://diagrams.mingrammer.com/) module to create diagrams.
I am generating different diagrams and looking for a way to control the size of png output, i.e I need that always have the same size

Thank you

I tried using :
`graph_attr = { "size":     "7.75" }`

But it does not work as I wanted